# Left join how can i use where if right field exists

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join, count, where-clause

i have two tables:

users (used fields in query) ->

```
 |uuid|name|last_name|email|rol        |status|
 |1234|abcd|   abc   |1@2.3|pre-thunder|  1   |
 |5678|efgh|   efg   |4@5.6|pre-thunder|  1   |
```

And documentation_thunder table (used fields in query)->

```
|id|id_thunder|doc_type|
|1 |1234      |image   |
```

I try to get all records on my left table but additional i get a count from my right table:

```
SELECT 
 users.uuid,
 users.email,
 users.name,
 users.last_name, 
 COUNT(documentation_thunder.id) as documentation// i need to know how many documents have the user
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN documentation_thunder
  ON users.uuid = documentation_thunder.id_thunder 
WHERE 
 users.status = 1 AND users.rol = 'pre-thunder' AND (documentation_thunder.doc_type = 'image' OR documentation_thunder.doc_type IS NULL)
```

This query only returns first user but i need returns all users no matter if not have documents.

Any idea? how do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to return a `count` for each user, you should also be using `group by`.  Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
SELECT 
 users.uuid,
 users.email,
 users.name,
 users.last_name, 
 COUNT(documentation_thunder.id) as documentation
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN documentation_thunder
  ON users.uuid = documentation_thunder.id_thunder 
WHERE 
 users.status = 1 AND users.rol = 'pre-thunder' AND 
 (documentation_thunder.doc_type = 'image' OR documentation_thunder.doc_type IS NULL)
GROUP BY users.uuid
```

Comment: Whoooaaaa You are the best. Thanks Giorgos